# discord.py FFMPEG Option reconnect not found

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm working on a music bot using discord.py, I've looked online and found that I needed to pass in ffmpeg options into discord.FFmpegPCMAudio() for the bot to not stop half way through the song. However it returns an error "Option reconnect not found."

```
vc = await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect()

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': 'C:/Luke/YoutubeDLAudio/audio.mp3',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192'
    }],
    'prefer_ffmpeg': True,
    'keepvideo': True
}

ffmpeg_opts = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5','options': '-vn'}   # <---------------

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])

vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Luke/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source="C:/Luke/YoutubeDLAudio/audio.mp3", **ffmpeg_opts))    <--------------
```

Does anyone know the problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `'before_options'` should be part of `ydl_opt`, not `ffmpeg_opts`